# TFS - SQL Server - Jenkins Integration

Tags: sql-server-2008, jenkins-pipeline

Need ideas for TFS - Jenkins integration.
Using TFS for Sql server database - Database objects such as table,views, SP & functions. Got 3 environments.
Now planning to implement Jenkins continuous integration.

Can someone provide an idea to implement jenkins with TFS for SQL DB objects for 3 environment(DEV/QA/PROD).

Comment: Are you using TFS 2013 XAML build by now?

Answer (score 0):

According to your tag, seems you are still stay with the old XAML build definition on TFS2013.

Your question is too board. If you are moving to the new web-based vNext system. Either upgrade your TFS version or directly use VSTS. It' not hard to achieve the TFS/VSTS and Jenkins Integration. Details please refer below two blogs:

- [TFS and Jenkins Integration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/12/31/tfs-and-jenkins-integration/)
- [Visual Studio Team Services Integration with Jenkins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/)

Add a section:

> Team Services integration with Jenkins **allows using both CI systems
>   with traceability through a single DevOps platform**.  This post
>   summarizes Team Services’ initial capabilities of integrating with
>   Jenkins.  Supported scenarios include:
>
> - Using Jenkins for continuous integration of Team Services Git    repositories
> - Using Jenkins to validate Team Services pull requests
> - Mixing Jenkins and Team Services to perform builds and releases
> - Providing traceability between Jenkins and Team Services; linking    builds, pull requests, commits, and stories

For 3 environment(DEV/QA/PROD), you could use TFS [Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management) to do the [Continuous Integration and Delivery](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/continuous-integration/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the source projects are in TFS and you want to do build in Jenkins.

You just need to add TFS-plugin to Jenkins, then you can specify TFS source in job configuration.

[jenkinsci/tfs-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin)